# cat command appears to be adding extra $ character at the end of each line

Tags: files, cat, wc

I am trying to create a file and it looks like the `vi` editor is adding a `$` at the end of each line. I don't know what's causing this or how to prevent `vi` from doing it.

```
vi file.txt
12345
abcde

cat -v -e file.txt
12345$
abcde$

wc file.txt
2 2 12
```

I don't want those `$` symbols at the end; they break my automation files which depend on character count. Why would word count shows 12 characters when in fact each line has 5 characters?

VIM version 7.4.629

Comment: The $ symbols are added by`cat` because you used the `-e` flag (*show line endings*)

Comment: No, they are not added by cat.  See the updated question

Comment: `wc` includes newlines (linefeed characters) in its count

Comment: Your "automation files" are perhaps overly fragile; have you considered posting them on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@steeldriver's comment is correct: `cat` shows line-endings with `$` (as `vi` might if you asked it nicely, using ":set list").  The extra character per line is the newline (an invisible character at the end of each line of text).

If you want only a count of the *printable* text, you could filter the file before processing it with `wc`, e.g., using `tr` with the `-d` option.  Here is a script which counts itself as an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat $0 |wc
cat $0 | tr -d '\r\n\t' | wc
cat $0 | tr -d '[:cntrl:]' |wc
```

though the last line is possibly not portable enough for your use (it is in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html), in the *extended* section).   But it will run on anything you're likely to be using, based on the clues in the rationale.

Comment: I understand cat -v -e shows extra characters including the unprintable characters. But it does not explain me as to why word count is not coming out as 10.

Comment: `wc` is showing the total number of characters in the file: 5 visible characters for each of 2 lines, plus one extra invisible character (per line). 2 times (5 + 1) = 12.

Comment: ok, thanks, so how whould i get the character count of only printable characters in file ?